# node.js connect-form image upload to tmp directory

Tags: file-upload, node.js, express

I uploading the images using connect-form and express as in https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/cbdd907393e6fc9cf4eb092237241d1626a9a98d/examples/multipart/app.js.

The images get saved to /tmp directory.
I want to change it from /tmp to some directory that is within the application context. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set

```
req.form.uploadDir = "<your_path>";
```

and the file is saved in the fixed path.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [utils.pump](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.5.7/api/util.html#util.pump) to move the file to some other dir.

Comment: I thought about moving the file using "sys", but that would be one more extra operation. doesn't "express" or "connect-form" make it a configurable option ? also i'm using node 0.4.11, so is util.pump available there as well ? need to check.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can set a temporary dir other then "tmp". Re: 0.4.11, yes: http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.1/api/util.html#util.pump

Answer (score 0):

best is to configure uploadDir  :

```
app.use(express.bodyParser({uploadDir:__dirname+'/uploads'}));
```

Comment: If you do, be aware of this issue: http://andrewkelley.me/post/do-not-use-bodyparser-with-express-js.html